# Show it is a sigma-field

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field on $R$ and $\Omega$ is a Borel set so that $\Omega\in B$, I want to show that $\{C\cap \Omega:C\in B\}$ is a $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\Omega$. So I need to show three conditions. It's easy to show that $\emptyset$ is in the set since we can take $C$ as an empty set. But if I let $A=C^*\cap\Omega$, where $C^*\in B$ I cannot show $A^c$ also in this set. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A \in \{ C \cap \Omega: C \in B \} =: \mathcal{F}$. Then $A = C \cap \Omega$ for some Borel $C$. Now $\Omega - A = \Omega \cap (C^{c} \cup \Omega^{c}) = \Omega \cap C^{c} \in \mathcal{F}$ because $C^{c}$ is Borel.